# Can't set extra empty lines for prompt in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I've read in [the docs for *PSReadLineOption*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7#parameters) that I can amend empty lines below the prompt to separate output from the next input. So I've tried the following.

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -ExtraPromptLineCount 3
```

As far I can tell, there's not empty lines appearing and I'm uncertain if I'm doing it wrong, if I'm imagining the result differently than intended or whatever is up with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish can be done in a simpler way. At the end of your output, just write a newline `` "`n" `` to stdout.

```
Write-Host "`n"
```

Sequences such as `` `n `` which use the back tick `` ` `` which is the PowerShell escape character, and a letter to make an escape sequence. These are called [special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7). In the specific case of `` `n ``, it represents a newline. In the docs I linked, it lists the escape sequences that you can use within PowerShell, to implement these special characters.

Comment: That's a very pragmatic way and definitely worth a +1. However, I'm curious about the specific parameter and how it works. Apparently, in a different way than I imagine. Care to share some info on that as well? Also, As *`n* seems to enter a new line, I automatically wonder if there are other characters with special powers like this. Care to provide a listing of such and perhaps even a link with a reference to a docs describing them?